# How to store some uninitialized address space for data storage in DTCM in assembly code (ARM-v7, STMCubeIDE)?

Tags: arm, stm32, armv7, linker-scripts

I have some initialized data that I store in the `.data` section. Then I use uninitialized address space using the `.bss` section. I have the DTCM enabled and I can store and read data from there via `__attribute__((section(".dtcm")))` when **written in C code**, and this confirms that my linker script is properly set up. However, I don't know what the equivalent expression is for using the address space **in assembly code**. I don't want to store the whole `.bss` section in DTCM, just a subset of data on which I wish to have faster access. How is this done?

Is there an authoritative document for assembly coding ARM ASM? I've used [this](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/ARM-ASM-Tutorial) so far and it's been very useful but it doesn't cover my case in general and tightly coupled memory in particular.

FWIW, this is for an STM32H745.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that the `.bss` section is zero-initialized, not uninitialized.

In assembly you can write `.section .dtcm`.  Since this is not a standard section name, you should probably set the flags to let the linker know what type of segment the section can be allocated to, eg: `.section .dtcm, "aw", %nobits`

You will want to read the [GNU as manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html#ELF-Version) for details of the `.section` directive.

This [ARM community blog post](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/useful-assembler-directives-and-macros-for-the-gnu-assembler) may be helpful as well.